# The function that I built only works in unity, what is the solution?

Tags: flutter, dart, admob

i have this void

```
void _showInterstitialAd() {
    if (_interstitialAd != null) {
      _interstitialAd!.fullScreenContentCallback = FullScreenContentCallback(
        onAdDismissedFullScreenContent: (InterstitialAd ad) {
          ad.dispose();
          _createInterstitialAd();
        },
        onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: (InterstitialAd ad, AdError error) {
          ad.dispose();
          _createInterstitialAd();
        },
      );
      _interstitialAd!.show();
    }
  }
```

I'm passing it inside a listView

```
 body: FutureBuilder(
          future: data.getBusiness(),
          builder: (context, snap) =>
              snap.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting
                  ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
                  : ListView.builder(
                      physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) => buildCardNews(
                        context,
                        data.business?[index],
                        _showInterstitialAd,
                      ),
                      itemCount: data.business!.length,
                    ),
        ),
```

and receive it inside the widget

```
Widget buildCardNews(context, article, Function()? function) {
  return InkWell(
    onTap: () {
      Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute<void>(
          builder: (BuildContext context) =>
              WebViewScreen(article['url'], article['source']['name']),
        ),
      );
      function;
    },
```

It takes me to the next screen, but the void you passed does not work
It only works if you put it directly like this:

```
Widget buildCardNews(context, article, Function()? function) {
  return InkWell(
    onTap: function,
```

But I don't want like this I want to be with the Navigator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a function:

```
Function? functionName;
```

Then there are a couple of ways you can use it:

- The keyword `functionName` refers to the function **itself**. This way you can pass this function as a parameter like you did.
- If you use parenthesis beside the function name, you are calling this function and getting its result: `functionName()`. You use this way when you want to run the content of the function.

In your example:

```
onTap: () {
      [...]
      function; <--- This is only a reference. You should use function();
    },
```

You created a function using the anonymous callback structure: `(){}`, which creates a function object and passes its reference to the `onTap`. So inside of it, if you want to call the interstitialAd, you should include the parenthesis (`function()`). The way it is `function` is just a reference to the function and therefore does not execute anything.

In the other case, you are passing only the reference to the function, which is what the inkwell expects:

`onTap: function`

When you are in doubt just ask yourself if you want the content of the function to be called, or you need to pass a reference for it to be called in a later moment.